# Microsoft Word Issue - Preventing Formatting From Automatically Being Altered When Transitioning from .doc to .docx File

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting, conditional-formatting

I have Microsoft Word .doc files that are formatted perfectly. When transitioning the .doc files to .docx the formatting automatically is being altered/changed and I have to spend time fixing the formatting over again. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

Many people have encountered this same problem.
Below is one solution that worked for some of them:

- Save As the document in RTF format
- Select All and Copy to the clipboard
- Start a new `.docx` document
- Paste the clipboard into the document.

If it worked correctly, the formatting wouldn't be lost this way.

Answer (score 0):

Likely, the templates used to *create* the .doc differ from the current templates for .docx in MS *Word*. Here are two things you might try:

- [Edit the default *Word* templates](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/edit-template-ms-word-53741.html) to correspond to the preferred document style. For example, set the default text body font to your old preferences. If necessary, [install old fonts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/windows-10-missing-fonts) you preferred.
- Try a third-party tool to convert the documents, such as free [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) *Writer*. You can [edit or download](https://www.libreofficetemplates.net/) the templates for *Writer*, as well. The tool *might* create files more to your liking... or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an online converter: https://www.freeconvert.com/doc-to-docx

Comment: Why that'd be better than doing it in Word?